# JavaScript splitting String with multiple quotation marks and different IDs

Tags: javascript, split, quotation-marks

I have Strings which look like this one, but with different `Id`.

```
[{"Id":33,"Title":"Sweden, Stockholm - Järfälla: Dienstag, 31. Januar 2017 - Mittwoch, 1. Februar 2017"}]
```

How can I split them so that they become:

```
Sweden, Stockholm - Järfälla: Dienstag, 31. Januar 2017 - Mittwoch, 1. Februar 2017
```

I know that I can represent the quotation marks using `\"`, but I don't know how to apply the `split` or `String.prototype.split` function in this case.

I tried

```
var text = "[{\"Id\":33,\"Title\":\"Sweden, Stockholm - Järfälla: Dienstag, 31. Januar 2017 - Mittwoch, 1. Februar 2017\"}]".replace("[{\"Id\":33,\"Title\":\"", '');


alert(text);
```

But that would still leave `"}]` at the end and besides, the Strings have different ID's so that would only work for this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried to parse the string as json?

Comment: You probably want to do a `JSON.parse` and grab the string from the *Title* property.

Comment: You accepted the answer which didn't address your  original question - about splitting

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Thanks for the notification. I marked yours as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse`

```js
var text = "[{\"Id\":33,\"Title\":\"Sweden, Stockholm - Järfälla: Dienstag, 31. Januar 2017 - Mittwoch, 1. Februar 2017\"}]"
console.log(JSON.parse(text)[0].Title.split(","))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a JSON-string right? So, no splitting needed

```js
const x = JSON.parse('[{"Id":33,"Title":"Sweden, Stockholm - Järfälla: Dienstag, 31. Januar 2017 - Mittwoch, 1. Februar 2017"}]');
// now x is an Array
console.log(x);
// it's first element is an Object
// and you can extract the 'Title' property
console.log(x[0].Title);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```